# Select all woocommerce customers with pending orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I select all woocommerce customers with pending status on an order.  I am looking specifically for the customers list and emails not the specific orders.

So I know I can get all pending orders with this:

```
    $unpaid_orders = (array) wc_get_orders( array(
    'limit'        => -1,
    'status'       => 'pending',
    ));
```

But I want to just have the array of customers with pending orders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done it correct. You have to loop the resultant order array `$unpaid_orders` to collect customer IDs.

```
$customers = []; // Array to collect customer IDs
$unpaid_orders = (array) wc_get_orders( array(
'limit'        => -1,
'status'       => 'pending',
));
foreach ($unpaid_orders as $order) { // Looping all orders to fetch customer IDs
    array_push($customers, $order->get_customer_id());
}
```